# C++ randomized number always same even with time(0) as seed

Tags: c++, random

Hi I'm trying to generate some random numbers which will be converted to chars later. The problem is the number generated by rand() always return the same although I've used time(0) as the seed for the rand().

```
int randomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    srand(time(0)); 
    int rndm = (rand()%(max-min))+min;
    cout<<rndm<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say I generate the random 3 times

```
int main()
{
    randomNumber(0,5);
    randomNumber(0,5);
    randomNumber(0,5);
}
```

The numbers produced will be 1 1 1 or 2 2 2 etc. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Don't seed it every time! Only seed it once!

Comment: Call the `srand()` only once in `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reseeding the pseudo-random sequence with the same seed before each call to `rand`, since the value returned by `time` only changes once a second. That causes you to get the same result each time.

Only call `srand` once, at the start of the program.

Better still, look at the C++11 `<random>` library, which has more sophisticated generators and access to "true" random numbers for seeding them.

Comment: oh I see.. thanks for the explanation. I'll take a look at the library too later.